# Is there someway to lock the screen by ViewModel during a task?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Is there someway to lock the screen of app by ViewModel during a task? I'm creating a plugin to make that, but i don't wanna create something that already exists. I need something that locks the screen by the ViewModel withou a XAML code in the View. Something like Rg.Plugin.PopUp makes with popups, but, instead that, creating a leayer to wait the task.

Comment: Check [ACR User Dialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs), you could use the `ShowLoading` when start a task and `HideLoading` when it finish.

Comment: Hi FabriBertani, please add that like a response for me to accept like a best response.

Comment: Problem solved! @FabriBertani